# WCF Service function calls itself again

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, wcf

I am doing an ajax call to a wcf function,after it call it execute complete function properly and save in all table but at end in Return instead it call function again , and complete function execute again without error and in return it is going to Ajax error.

I have no idea what i am doing wrong.

Thanks in Advance.
Any Help will be appropriated.

Comment: i found issue that was due to parsing error in datetime variable.